# how can i change gray scale range of HU unit of .raw image data to all positive values

Tags: python

i have .raw volume data of CT lung images having pixel intensities values in HU unit from negative to positive values, i need to convert the values to all >0. like converting to 0-255 range int16 signed integer. please suggest.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it. I converted.raw into dcm with change of range using Mevislab n then converted back to raw file to get all positive values.